# How can I draw curved lines continuously in android?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

[image: Curved Lines]

Can you please help me out how to draw curved lines continuously in android ?

Comment: I had search half of the internet but did not find the solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution, as you mentioned, is to simply connect the points with a straight line. Here's the code to do so:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Path path = new Path();
    boolean first = true;
    for(Point point : points){
        if(first){
            first = false;
            path.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
        }
        else{
            path.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
        }
    }
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
make sure you change your paint from fill to stroke:

paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
Another option is to connect the points with iterpolation using the quadTo method:

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Path path = new Path();
    boolean first = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < points.size(); i += 2){
        Point point = points.get(i);
        if(first){
            first = false;
            path.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
        }

        else if(i < points.size() - 1){
            Point next = points.get(i + 1);
            path.quadTo(point.x, point.y, next.x, next.y);
        }
        else{
            path.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
        }
    }

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

This still results in some sharp edges.

If you're really ambitious, you can start to calculate the cubic splines as follows:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Path path = new Path();

    if(points.size() > 1){
        for(int i = points.size() - 2; i < points.size(); i++){
            if(i >= 0){
                Point point = points.get(i);

                if(i == 0){
                    Point next = points.get(i + 1);
                    point.dx = ((next.x - point.x) / 3);
                    point.dy = ((next.y - point.y) / 3);
                }
                else if(i == points.size() - 1){
                    Point prev = points.get(i - 1);
                    point.dx = ((point.x - prev.x) / 3);
                    point.dy = ((point.y - prev.y) / 3);
                }
                else{
                    Point next = points.get(i + 1);
                    Point prev = points.get(i - 1);
                    point.dx = ((next.x - prev.x) / 3);
                    point.dy = ((next.y - prev.y) / 3);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    boolean first = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++){
        Point point = points.get(i);
        if(first){
            first = false;
            path.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
        }
        else{
            Point prev = points.get(i - 1);
            path.cubicTo(prev.x + prev.dx, prev.y + prev.dy, point.x - point.dx, point.y - point.dy, point.x, point.y);
        }
    }
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

Also, I found that you needed to change the following to avoid duplicate motion events:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        Point point = new Point();
        point.x = event.getX();
        point.y = event.getY();
        points.add(point);
        invalidate();
        Log.d(TAG, "point: " + point);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

and add the dx & dy values to the Point class:

```
class Point {
    float x, y;
    float dx, dy;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return x + ", " + y;
    }
}
```

This produces smooth lines, but sometimes has to connect the dots using a loop. Also, for long drawing sessions, this becomes computationally intensive to calculate.

Hope that helps... fun stuff to play around with.

Edit

I threw together a quick project demonstrating these different techniques, including Square's suggessted signature implementation. Enjoy: https://github.com/johncarl81/androiddraw

Answer (score 0):

You can use a chart library, like `mpandroidchart`: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Draw the linechart while removing your labels and your grids. It should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but Chart library is not working for this problem.

Comment: I dont understand why, it can do the trick easily. You can still have a look on some library using openGL to draw it directly, then

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.example.lines.R.layout.activity_main);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);

    Bitmap bg = Bitmap.createBitmap(480,800, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas can = new Canvas(bg);

    int left1 = 10;
    int top1 = 10;
    int right1 = 30;
    int bottom1 = 30;

    for(int j=0; j< 31; j++)
    {

        for(int i=0; i<23;i++)
        {
            RectF rectF1 = new RectF(left1,top1,right1,bottom1);
            can.drawArc(rectF1, 0, 180, false, paint);

            left1 = right1;
            right1 = left1+20;
        }
        System.out.println("\n");

        left1 = 10;
        top1 = bottom1 + 1;
        right1 = 30;
        bottom1 = 30+top1 - 6;

    }

    LinearLayout l1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(com.example.lines.R.id.drawarea);
    l1.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bg));

}
```

Comment: activity_main.xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/drawarea">
</LinearLayout>

Comment: Is this an answer to the question or is it part of the question, KhiLan?

Comment: I figure out the solution. And for solution check above thread. @Pang